# State In ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

If there are multiple components at different hierarchy levels that use the same data, should I model the data with different variables represented in the respective states of each component or should I have it as a single field included in the state of a component higher up in the hierarchy, possibly the root element? How does it affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do, to minimize the juggling of states IF every component or thereabouts, needs something from the parent.. I will put that behavior in the parent. So, lets say I have a "Parent component" that makes an api call to get some data. If most of my children needs different splices of data off of that api call response.. I would do..

```
PARENT
state = from api response
----> Child Component 1 {...slice of state it needs}
----> Child Component 2 {...slice of state it needs}
---------> Sub Child Component 1 {... slice of state it needs from component 2}
```

Or if I can't really know for sure what data each child needs over time, I'll pass down the whole state from the parent into each of my components. If those child components have sub-components, then the child components will continue to pass the state down thru the props. You can also look into "Context" that is a nice solution if you want to leapfrop all of the passing down, and just have it available to all the children.

I usually don't worry about "performance" unless I'm dealing with literally hundreds of data sets. In which case, I tend to pass down only what the child and its sub-children needs.